# Firebase Job Dispatcher failing to schedule jobs on One Plus Devices

Tags: android, background-service, android-background, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am using Firebase Job Dispatcher to schedule jobs

```
Driver driver = new GooglePlayDriver(context);
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);

        Job pedometerReminderJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                                    .setService(PedometerService.class)
                                    .setTag(PEDOMETER_JOB_TAG)
                                    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                                    .setRecurring(true)
                                    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0,60))
                                    .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                                    .build();

        dispatcher.schedule(pedometerReminderJob);
```

I have checked on some devices for e.g nexus 6p, Samsung galaxy s7, Xiomi Devices(Where I have asked permission to enable the application in the auto-start). But however, I am facing problem to schedule it on One Plus devices (The job services start for some time but then it abruptly stops.)